# SAS Rename of file with open parentheses

Tags: sas, macros, file-rename, quoting

I have a large number of Excel files to be processed. I've created code that reads their names into a dataset for execution of each file. Each of the files, unfortunately, has an open left parentheses like "(", such as: Jason (Allen.xlsx

I've written code to clean up the names in my listing data set, but I can't seem to get the RENAME based macro to work with the open parentheses. Using two dummy Excel files, the first record in the school_file_list dataset will change names just fine because it has closed parentheses...but the second file name will not change. Is there a way to edit my macro to feed it the file names that have the offending open parentheses?

```
data school_file_list;
    input fname $ 1-18 newfname $ 20-42;
    cards;
Jason (Allen).xlsx Jason Allen.xlsx
Jason (A.xlsx      Jason A.xlsx
;
run; 

%let filepath= %nrbquote(C:\mypath\);

%macro file_rename(from, to);
data _null_;
    rc=rename("&filepath.&from", "&filepath.&to", "file");
    if rc ne 0 then do;
        put "Rename of file &from to &to DID NOT WORK!!!" rc=;
        call symput('err','1');
    end;
    else put "Rename of file &from to &to WORKED.";
    run;
%mend file_rename;

data _null_; set school_file_list;
    call execute ('%file_rename(from='||strip(fname)||', to='||strip(newfname)||');');
    run;
```

Comment: Does the second file rename fail because you just renamed "Jason (Allen).xlsx" to "Jason Allen.xlsx" which is the same name you are trying to rename "Jason (Allen.xlsx" to "Jason Allen.xlsx" which already exists?

Comment: Do you get an error or bad log note?

Comment: Yeah, i realized i made a mistake in my example...I edited it accordingly so that both file names would be different after renaming.  When i attempt the one with only a single parenthesis, i get a ERROR: MACRO PARAMETER CONTAINS SYNTAX ERROR

Comment: Why are you using macro code to do the renaming instead of just using the regular SAS code?  Unlike macro code SAS code does not have any trouble with parentheses in strings.

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure i understand your comment...i'm using macro code because i'm trying to process all of the files contained in the school_file_list data set. In my example, there are only 2. In my actual problem...I have several hundred. Are you telling me i can accomplish that without using the file_rename macro?

Comment: Why are you moving the filename from an actual variable where things like ( or & or % do not cause any trouble into a macro variable?  And if your macro does need to take in strings you could include the quotes into the value passed to the macro so that any special characters are ignored by the macro processor.

Comment: Don't use the macro, it's not needed for this situation.  Do them all in one pass through the listing data in a plain DATA Step.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me the issue is the macro and not the names or the renaming. Not sure what value the macro is adding in this process.  Why not just issue the rename statements directly in the data step?

```
data _null_;
  set school_file_list;
  rc=rename(cats("&filepath",fname),cats("&filepath",newfname),"file");
...
```

If you need to make a macro then make one that takes the name of the dataset as the input.

Something like this:

```
%macro file_rename(dsname,from=from,to=to,filepath=" ");
data _null_;
  set &dsname;
  rc=rename(cats(&filepath,&from),cats(&filepath,&to),"file");
  if rc ne 0 then do;
     put "Rename of file " &from "to " &to "in " &filepath "DID NOT WORK!!!" rc=;
     call symput('err','1');
  end;
  else put "Rename of file " &from "to " &to "in " &filepath "WORKED.";
run;
%mend file_rename;
```

Which for your example dataset and root path you could call like this:

```
%file_rename
(dsname=school_file_list
,from=fname
,to=newfname
,filepath="&filepath"
);
```

Which will generate code like:

```
894  %let filepath=c:\;
895  %file_rename(dsname=school_file_list,from=fname,to=newfname,filepath="&filepath");
MPRINT(FILE_RENAME):   data _null_;
MPRINT(FILE_RENAME):   set school_file_list;
MPRINT(FILE_RENAME):   rc=rename(cats("c:\",fname),cats("c:\",newfname),"file");
MPRINT(FILE_RENAME):   if rc ne 0 then do;
MPRINT(FILE_RENAME):   put "Rename of file " fname "to " newfname "in " "c:\" "DID NOT WORK!!!" rc=;
MPRINT(FILE_RENAME):   call symput('err','1');
MPRINT(FILE_RENAME):   end;
MPRINT(FILE_RENAME):   else put "Rename of file " fname "to " newfname "in " "c:\" "WORKED.";
MPRINT(FILE_RENAME):   run;
```

With a minor change

```
%if %length(&dsname) %then %do;
  set &dsname;
%end;
```

you could also make the macro work without a dataset.

```
%file_rename
(from='Jason (Allen).xlsx'
,to='Jason Allen.xlsx'
,filepath="&filepath"
);
```